# How do I round a floating point number to a certain precision in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, formatting

I have a variable (it happens to be a file size) whose value is `16.0986328125`.

I want to print it as `16.098` (using three places past the decimal point.)

How can I do this?  Here's what I have so far:

```
$filesize = 16.0986328125;
echo $filesize.' KB';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`printf`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf("%0.3f KB", $filesize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `round` function.

Comment: Wouldn't that round it to 16.099, not 16.098?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function